# URL rewrite in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting

I have a page that displays a post by passing its id through GET or POST.

*For example:
www.example.com/post/viewpost?id=PostTiTle*

But I want **achieve** this like:
**www.example.com/post/PostTiTle**

So post id should be in URL using single controller. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This will work with the default routing. What have you tried?

Comment: no, routing is unknown to me in MVC 3

Comment: Start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't modify any of the settings default MVC routing examples should work.

Example

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    // do something with variable id = PostTiTle
}
```

If your controller name is **Post** and your action name is **ViewPost** then you need to add additional route like so.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Post",
    "post/{id}",
    new { controller = "Post", action = "ViewPost", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: it is working with default routing, but it is not what i want,
i want to sent id like this
 www.example.com/post/PostTiTle

Comment: @ShahzaibAliKhan Tell me your Controller name and Action name and I will show you what you need to type in routes.